# QBasic - How do you create a file of any kind in QBasic?

Tags: dos, file-management, qbasic

I'm trying to create a batch file, a text file, and a DLL file via QBasic?

Please help me... I'm making a fake DOS.

Comment: A text file and a DLL file in QBasic for a fake DOS? I have no clue what you're asking here..

Comment: If you look at DOSbox it may contain certain information on what a DOS is.

Answer (score 5):

That's old :)

If i remind:

To Open files: (you can create, read and write)

```
Open (Path and file name) For (Mode) [Access (Type of access)] As #(File number)
```

Where:

(Path and file name) - The path and name of the destination file

(Mode) - You can set one of this values:

```
  Input:  Read Mode
  Binary: Structured data
  Output: Write Mode - If the file already exist - overwrites the file.
  Append: The difference between this and Output is that if the file already exists, the content is appended to the end of the file
```

(Access type) - Kind of access.

```
  Read:  Read-Only access.
  Write: Write-Only access.
  Read Write: Available only in Append Mode
```

(File number) - Identifies the file, like a pointer to it.

To close a file, just use:

```
Close [#(FileNumber)][, #(FileNumber) ...]
```

Yes you can close more than one file at a time, and if you don't specify the file number, qbasic will close all your opened files.

Note that in Append and Output mode, you must first close the file before you open it for reading!

Ok, to read\write use the same you use on screen, but append the file destination:

```
Input (Char Length), #(File number), (Name of the Variable)
Line Input #(File number), (Name of the Variable)
Print #(File number), (Data) [or (Binary data)]
```

If you don't remember to give the carriage-return (commonly \n) use the ASCII char: Chr(10)

Example:

```
Open "c:\test.bat" for Output as #1
Print #1, "@echo off" + Chr$(10)
Print #1, "echo Hello World"
Close #1
End
```